# How to dump multiple databases of the same cluster in single execution?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I have 100 databases in my cluster. I need to backup 30 databases (as single file or multiple file, anything is fine). I could do it for tables using `pg_dump` with `-t`.

Is there any way to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
pg_dump -d db1 -d db2 -d db3 -Fc > dbs_backup.backup
```

Comment: No, not possible. `pg_dump` can only dump data from a single database

Answer (score 4):

**`pg_dump`** dumps a ***single*** DB. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

> pg_dump only dumps a single database. To back up an entire cluster, or
> to back up global objects that are common to all databases in a
> cluster (such as roles and tablespaces), use [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html).

**`pg_dumpall`** dumps the whole DB cluster, including
global objects (roles, tablespaces, ...).
Postgres 12 adds the switch **`--exclude-database`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html#id-1.9.4.14.6)

> `--exclude-database=pattern`
>
> Do not dump databases whose name matches pattern. [...]

A specific DB name in the connection string is ignored. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html)

> `-d connstr`
> `--dbname=connstr`
>
> Specifies parameters used to connect to the server, as a connection
> string. See [Section 34.1.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) for more information.
>
> The option is called `--dbname` for consistency with other client
> applications, but because pg_dumpall needs to connect to many
> databases, the database name in the connection string will be ignored.
> Use the `-l` option to specify the name of the database used for the
> initial connection, which will dump global objects and discover what
> other databases should be dumped.

To dump *some* DBs but not all, use a shell script, like has been advised. You may want to include commands to create each DB in the dump:

- [How to get a pg_dump -s to include the CREATE DATABASE command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24760286/939860)

Comment: `pg_dumpall` can still be used with the `--exclude-database` flag to dump only some databases

Comment: Thanks, I added the new option above!

Answer (score 1):

Create a txt file with database names, one per line like:

```
db1
db2
db3
```

and so on for all db, then from shell:

```
for a in  `cat filename.txt`; do pg_dump -d $a > /tmp/${a}_backup.out; done
```

by
M.

P.S. I'm not able to write correctly (cannot understand why) but the filename.txt MUST be enclosed by "grave accent" (code U+0060)

Comment: I aware of other alternatives through scripts. Just I wonder is there any new parameter or any function available to achieve the same. Anyway, thanks for your time.